Binding value to multiple switches vue.js
I am trying to get different configs with the same ID to mirror each other through el-switches. What I will type below is only a portion of the template and script but I will happily provide more context if needed. The code I have right now is as follows:
<el-switch v-else-if="item.Type == 'bool'"
class="float-left margin-top-8"
v-model="item.Value[UserSelected.Instance]"
:id="item.Id"
:ref="item.Id"
:disabled="item.disabled"
:active-value="1"
:inactive-value="0"
@change="ModifiedSet(index, UserSelected.Instance, item.Id)"

ModifiedSet: function(indexOnPage, inst, id) {
    this.PageDisplay[indexOnPage].Modified.splice(inst, 1, true);
    this.UserSelected.Uid = id;
            
    // Find items with duplicate IDs
    let duplicateIds = this.findDuplicateIds(Object.values(this.UidItemList));

    // Sync values for duplicate IDs
    if (duplicateIds.includes(id)) {
        this.syncDuplicateValues(id);
    }

    // Scan for UID Value modifications
    this.CountModified();
},

syncDuplicateValues: function(duplicateId) {
    let items = Object.values(this.UidItemList);
    let duplicateItems = items.filter(item => item.Id === duplicateId);
    let valueToSync = duplicateItems[0].Value[this.UserSelected.Instance];

    // Sync value for all duplicate items
    duplicateItems.forEach(item => {
    item.Value[this.UserSelected.Instance] = valueToSync;
    });
},

findDuplicateIds: function(items) {
    let idCount = {};
    items.forEach(item => {
        let id = item.Id;
    idCount[id] = (idCount[id] || 0) + 1;
    });

    let duplicateIds = [];
    for (let id in idCount) {
         if (idCount[id] > 1) {
        duplicateIds.push(id);
    }
    }

    return duplicateIds;
},
/>```



The code nearly works, all switches that are not duplicates change as normal, however when a switch with a duplicate Id is changed only the first instance of the item.id value changes. I can change all duplicate switches by using the first switch but none of the switches that are not the first instance will change when I press them. I have tried changing the v-model, watchers, completely different methods and this was the closest I could get but am still missing something. Any help is good help.


What are el-switches? Do you have a "before"/"after" result you want? Hard to understand exactly that given the current state of the question. Which version of Vue are you using btw?

el-switches are from ElementPlus' library https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/switch.html. My before result would be that when I press a switch with a duplicate value the first switch changes all other switches. What I want after some changes is that any switch I press will change all the switches with the same ID
